# how to remove duplicates from Combobox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select, combobox

I fill a combobox via Javascript as follows:

```
let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = elem.businessObject.get('id');
    option.value = elem.businessObject.get('id');
    taskTypeEl.appendChild(option);
```

whereby taskTypeE1 refers to the select - tag from my html-code

but unfortunately, I fill my combobox with a lot of duplicates. Is there an easy way
to get rid of that, such that every item only appears once?
Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: **Aside note:** If it's possible, remove the duplicates in the backend side.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `dictionary` before starting the insertion of options, and only add the ones with the values that were not added before:

```
    let dictionary = {}; //initiate
```

So when iterating to add the options, you can check if it is unique like this:

```
    if(!dictionary[elem.businessObject.get('id')]){ //check for prev insertion
         let option = document.createElement("option");
         option.innerHTML = elem.businessObject.get('id');
         option.value = elem.businessObject.get('id');
         taskTypeEl.appendChild(option);
         dictionary[elem.businessObject.get('id')] = option; //add option
    }
```